# ORA-01722: invalid number error near date

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am trying to execute this insert statement into an oracle table but am getting an `invalid number` error.  Oracle is pointing at the date as the issue. But I dont see the problem.

```
INSERT INTO DROPPER_VACATIONS 
VALUES (21111,
    to_char('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to_char('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    'CRONUSER',
    to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),
    'CRONUSER',
    NULL)
```

Comment: A hint on the table structure would help.

Comment: It's also good practise to always list the column names explicitely in the insert statement: `insert into dropper_vacations (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not dates, but chars. You would need to_date to convert them to dates, but that would be silly, since you apparently need them as chars anyway.

Or did you mean to use `to_date` to convert them to dates? That would be wise, since it is better to store dates as actual dates rather than chars.

Comment: But there would be no sense in applying `to_date()` on `sysdate` as that is already a date...

Comment: that was it, sometimes you see something so much you miss the simple things, thank you